# Integrating Google+ into website

Tags: google-plus

When searching for things on google I have noticed a lot of the website has "By: John Smith" under the website link.  This will link to the google+ account.  An example of this is if you type in "CSS Tricks" into google search you will see a picture of Chris Coyier and has stuff like "more by chris coyier,"  Does anyone know how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic you're interested in is authorship. There are a couple of ways to establish authorship at Google.

**The profile badge**

If you add the profile badge to your domain, it will help Google link your Google+ profile to content that you've created on that domain. You can add the profile badge by adding this code to your website.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plus href="https://plus.google.com/{profileId}" rel="author"></g:plus>
```

Or you can use the [configuration tool](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/personal-config) to generate code specific to your needs.

**Verifying your email and linking**

You can also establish your authorship by verifying your email and linking to that content from your Google+ profile. You can find the email verification form and more detailed instructions [here](https://plus.google.com/authorship).

Comment: Thank you that gets me started!  I couldn't figure this out for some reason